# What's the best/proper way to set up my database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database, image below, and I feel that there must be an efficient way to add separate books for each child. For example... there may be 50 clubbers in the database. Each clubber will be in their own book and to make it simple, each book has 10 sections a clubber must complete. I was thinking of making a table for each child with the 10 sections, but that would end up with over 50 tables in my database. I also thought of creating a table called book and just having that table contain the 10 sections, but the problem with that is each child may be in one of 8 different books. So one table called book wouldn't work either.

Does anyone have a good suggestion on how to set this up in the database? My ultimate goal is to have each child linked to one of the 8 books that is available. Then the database will track which section each child is in for their certain book. So... today clubber A could finish section 1 and 2 in book 1, but clubber B might only finish section 1 in book 2. I'm wanting to pull this information from the database to see where each clubber is in their books... but... I first need to set the database up correctly.

Should I create 8 separate tables for each of the books and have the table data be section 1... section 2...? Or should I create one table and list 8 books in it and then link that to another table that has the section info? Or is there an even better way?

Thanks for any help[image: ![mydatabase]

Comment: It would be best to read a [bunch of articles](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561) about this topic, and learn the processes and what each is used for, rather than just getting given an answer of what someone else thinks could be best for your site. Do some research on different table structures and relationships and see which names stand out as useful structures, and then research those names to get guides on how to implement and maintain them

Comment: Clubber: Someone who [often visits nightclubs](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clubber). A Book Nightclub. `Bangin'`. Literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a table for books, and a table for sections. sections would contain a book_id so it knows which book it's part of. Then you link your children to sections with a section_id showing which section they're up to. A query joining to books would show you which book that was part of.

If the children can be reading multiple books at the same time, then you'll need an intermediate table which logically sits in between the two containing both the child's id and the section id so multiple books can be associated with the same child.

Comment: This is exactly what I was asking for! Thank you! I searched many forums and images online for a week before asking this silly question. I was too stuck on the idea of linking children to the books, but linking them to the sections is working perfectly! It's even solving other issues I was running into! Thank you again!

Comment: No problem. It's a pretty standard design based on the principles of "normalisation" in relational databases - probably a good topic to study if you get stuck with this sort of thing in future :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an intermediate table child_parent that has id_child and id_parent from table child and table parent in each row, so you end up with n-n relation between child and parent.

Comment: give that children often have multiple parents (!), this is a useful suggestion in itself, but the OP was asking about how to represent which book the child was reading, and which section they were up to.